# Validation only required when value is not available

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code:

```
{!! Form::select('the_selection', ['' => 'Nothing', 'Foo' => 'Bar']) !!}
```

And the following:

```
<input class="input" name="the_other_field" type="text"/>
```

The `the_other_field` field should be required only when `the_selection` is not `''` .

So I tried tis validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    // 'recurring'        => 'required|nullable',
    'the_other_field'      => 'required_without:the_selection,|date_format:Y-m-d|after:today',
]);
```

But that doesnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `required_if`

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
   // 'recurring'         => 'required|nullable',
   'the_other_field'      => 'required_if:recurring,|required_without:the_selection,|date_format:Y-m-d|after:today',
]);
```

If this not working you may do this:

```
$rules = [
   'the_other_field' => ['date_format:Y-m-d', 'after:today'],
];

if ($request->get('the_selection') != null) {
    array_push($rules['the_other_field'], 'required');
}

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move your validation to a form request, then you could add a “sometimes” validation rule:

```php
class YourRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'the_selection' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->sometimes('the_other_field', 'required', function ($input) {
            return $input->the_selection != '';
        });
    }
}
```